# Create a User-Defined Convertion for Generic Type

Tags: c#, generics

I am trying to create a Cacheable object. My problem is that I want to allow the Cacheable object to directly convert it to T. I am trying to overide operator explicitly/implicitly but I'm still receiving the InvalidCastException.
Here is my Cacheable object

```
public class Cacheable<T> : ICacheable<T>, IEquatable<T>
{
    private Func<T> fetch;
    private T value { get; set; }

    public Cacheable(Func<T> fetch)
    {
        this.fetch = fetch;
    }

    public T Value
    {
        get
        {
            if (value == null) value = fetch();

            return value;
        }
    }

    public bool Equals(T other)
    {
        return other.Equals(Value);
    }

    public void Source(Func<T> fetch)
    {
        this.fetch = fetch;
    }

    public static implicit operator Cacheable<T>(Func<T> source)
    {
        return new Cacheable<T>(source);
    }

    public static explicit operator Func<T>(Cacheable<T> cacheable)
    {
        return cacheable.fetch;
    }

    public static explicit operator T(Cacheable<T> cacheable)
    {
        return cacheable.Value;
    }
}
```

and this is the code I am trying to use

```
public class prog
{
    public string sample()
    {
        var principal = new Cacheable<IPrincipal>(()=>{
             var user = HttpContext.Current.User;
             if (!user.Identity.IsAuthenticated) throw new UnauthorizedAccessException();
             return user;
        });

        return ((IPrincipal)principal).Identity.Name; //this is where the error occur
    }
}
```

Error Info:

An exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred in Connect.Service.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Unable to cast object of type 'Common.Cacheable`1[System.Security.Principal.IPrincipal]' to type 'System.Security.Principal.IPrincipal'.

Comment: Why you couldn't just write a method, such as `public T GetValue<T>()` and return `Value` from it.

Comment: i already have that method/public get property. i just want to let developers able to convert cacheable<T> to T.

Comment: principal.Value.Identity.Name will work, i just want that the cacheable be able to convert directly to T, any guest or is it possible?

Comment: i try to do it by overriding the implicit/explicit operator but it is not working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Explicite conversion does not Work when one of both values is a Interface you can read this here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664464(VS.71).aspx

To bring you program to work you need a Class that inherits from IPrincipal and cast like this:

```
return ((YourPrincipal)principal).Identity.Name;
```

This link shows you how to create your own Principal.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649210.aspx

Comment: thank you, it's clear now. upon trying to make do this code. i was able to convert it. var a = Cacheable<string>(()=> "sample"); var b = (string)a; // 'b' gets the value of a.Value; thanks

Comment: i also tried this one and it works var a = new Cacheable<HttpContext>(() => HttpContext.Current); var b = (HttpContext)a;

Comment: @VJPPaz can you mark it as awnser that other people see that it helped you or write a own awnser that worked for you?